# How to concat array of observables into one. throw error Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Observable<Message>[]'

Tags: websocket, rxjs, observable

angular v 6.1.10
typescript v 2.9.2
rxjs v 6.3.3
ng2-stmompjs v 7.0.0

I am using [ng2-stomp library](https://github.com/stomp-js/ng2-stompjs) for web sockets which create observable of will initiate a subscription which is observable. In my requirements, I am creating multiple channel subscriptions based on application id and now want to subscribe all these channels all in once or we can say higher order observable so tried to use the various rxjs operator `merge`, `mergeAll`, `concat` but nothing works so far. Here is what I have done so far.

Right now this one is working

```
appList = [{appID: '123'}, {appID: '345'}];


 const appList$ = appList.map((appID: string, idx: number) => {
            const headers = Object.assign({}, this.headers, { id: `app_${idx}` });
            const watcher = this.rxStompService.watch(`/topic/${appID}`, headers);
            console.log({ watcher }); // This is observable
            return watcher;
        });



appList$.forEach((app$) => {
            app$.subscribe((message: Message) => {
                const notification: Notification = JSON.parse(message.body);
                this.totalNotificationCount++;
                if (Object.keys(notification).length) {
                    this.notificationMessages.push(notification);
                }
            });
        });

{
  "watcher": { "_isScalar": false, "source": { "source": { "_isScalar": false } }, "operator": { "connectable": { "source": { "_isScalar": false } } } }
}
```

BUT I think we can concat all observables in one and can subscribe all. Note that I am unable to use `ForkJoin` because appList is dynamic and so the number of WebSocket. followings are my trail to convert multiple observable into once.

#### Trial 1: using `concat` and `map` operator

```
const batch = appList.map((appID, idx) => {
            console.log({ appID, idx });
            const headers = Object.assign({}, this.headers, { id: `app_${idx}` });
            const watcher = this.rxStompService.watch(`/topic/${appID}`, headers);
            return watcher;
        });



concat(...batch).pipe( map (i => i)).subscribe({ });
```

this gives error:

> Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction'.

#### trial 2: use subscribe all after `concat`

```
 concat(...batch).subscribe({
            next: (v: any) => console.log(v),
            complete: () => console.log('Complete')
        });
```

> Error: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction'.

#### Trail 3: using `pipe`

```
const appList$ = appList.map((appID: string, idx: number) => {
            const headers = Object.assign({}, this.headers, { id: `app_${idx}` });
            const watcher = this.rxStompService.watch(`/topic/${appID}`, headers);
            return watcher;
        });

        console.log({ appList$ });
        appList$.pipe(
            takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe),
            tap((i) => {
                console.log('tapping', i);
            })
        );
```

console.log({appList$}) return this[image: observable groups]

```
  {
  "appList$": [
    {
      "_isScalar": false,
      "source": {
        "source": {
          "_isScalar": false
        }
      },
      "operator": {
        "connectable": {
          "source": {
            "_isScalar": false
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_isScalar": false,
      "source": {
        "source": {
          "_isScalar": false
        }
      },
      "operator": {
        "connectable": {
          "source": {
            "_isScalar": false
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_isScalar": false,
      "source": {
        "source": {
          "_isScalar": false
        }
      },
      "operator": {
        "connectable": {
          "source": {
            "_isScalar": false
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_isScalar": false,
      "source": {
        "source": {
          "_isScalar": false
        }
      },
      "operator": {
        "connectable": {
          "source": {
            "_isScalar": false
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_isScalar": false,
      "source": {
        "source": {
          "_isScalar": false
        }
      },
      "operator": {
        "connectable": {
          "source": {
            "_isScalar": false
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_isScalar": false,
      "source": {
        "source": {
          "_isScalar": false
        }
      },
      "operator": {
        "connectable": {
          "source": {
            "_isScalar": false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

> Error: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Observable[]'

So my question is how to merge all observable into once and subscribe in once

Comment: did you try combineLatest?

Comment: I think in your trial 1 & 2, you should user concat(batch) instead of concat(...batch) because batch is already an array of observables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is amazing; whenever I write the question here and try again and I found the solution myself.

I have solved this way using `from` and `mergeMap` and thanks to [this angular in depth article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/practical-rxjs-in-the-wild-requests-with-concatmap-vs-mergemap-vs-forkjoin-11e5b2efe293)

```
private watchApplications(appList: string[]) {
 const appList$ = from(appList).pipe(
            mergeMap((appID, idx) => {
                const headers = Object.assign({}, this.headers, { id: `app_${idx}` });
                const watcher = this.rxStompService.watch(`/topic/${appID}`, headers);
                return watcher;
            })
        );
        appList$
            .pipe(
                takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe),
                tap((f: Frame) => {
                    console.log('tapping Frame', f);
                })
            )
            .subscribe((message: Message) => {
                const notification: Notification = JSON.parse(message.body);
                console.log({ notification });
                this.totalNotificationCount++;
                if (Object.keys(notification).length) {
                    this.notificationMessages.push(notification);
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: Yes, the power of the duck is not to be underestimated
https://rubberduckdebugging.com/